# SNAT through Racoon IPSec VPN

Tags: vpn, iptables, nat, ipsec

I am trying to route traffic from a device (that I will call "target") connected to my Ubuntu box (that I will call "host") to servers at a remote office.

The host uses a Racoon IPSec VPN, connected through a NIC called `efix`. This creates an aliased IF called `efix:0` which has IP adress `192.168.190.132`. It is able to reach the servers.

The link between host and target is an Ethernet link, using IP adresses `10.0.0.1` on IF `eusb` for the host and `10.0.0.2` on IF `eth0` for the target.

I have setup the following routes and iptables entries:

- On target:

  ```
  10.0.0.0 *        255.255.255.0 U  0 0 0 eth0
  default  10.0.0.1 0.0.0.0       UG 0 0 0 eth0
  ```
- On host:

  ```
  echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to 192.168.190.132
  iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
  ```

Using Wireshark to monitor an HTTP GET, I can see `SYN` packets from the target go all the way to the server, but the server's `SYNACK` packets stop at the host and are not forwarded to the target. Am I missing something here ? Isn't SNAT supposed to keep track of the connections ?

Comment: After some more reading: could the racoon IPSec stack be the issue here ? My connexion script only establishes tunnels between the remote VPN gateway and the `host` machine, maybe I should add a tunnel for the `10.0.0.0/24` segment ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely that your forward rule is relying on the SNAT to have already happened for the return packets.  When you say `iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.0/24", that relies on the traffic already having been changed via the NAT, which happens **after** the forwarding.  When the initial packet comes in, it has the NATed IP address (192.168.190.32) as the destination.

Probably what you want are rules like this:

```
iptables -A forward -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A -i efix -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.190.132
```

The first rule allows traffic related to existing connections, like the return traffic from the SNATed connections from "host".  The second accepts traffic from "host" (if I understand your layout, "host" passes traffic to your NATing firewall on it's "etho0" interface, right?).  You may further want to limit that rule with "-d 192.168.190.0/24", depending on your exact needs.

The last rule is what you have already posted, which says to SNAT the traffic.

Comment: My layout description might not be as clear as I thought. The layout is:

VPN <=> 192.168.190.132-efix:host:eusb-10.0.0.1 <=> 10.0.0.2-eth0:target

Comment: Ok, changing answer to reflect that.